# django how to pass parameter from url to view

Tags: python, regex, django, url, parameters

I'm trying to append a parameter `no_rep` at the end of my question url as a signal to show different views. I'm using **Django 1.8** and following the url pattern from askbot.

This is the **url.py**:

```
url(
        (r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % QUESTION_PAGE_BASE_URL.strip('/') +
        r'(%s)?' % r'/no-rep:(?P<no_rep>\w+)'),
        views.readers.question,
        name='question'
    ),
```

I'm trying to show different displays depending on the value of `no_rep` in my url.

This is the **view**:

```
def question(request, id, no_rep):
    if no_rep == '1':
        request.session['no_rep'] = True
    else:
        request.session['no_rep'] = False
```

I couldn't find information on what the +,%,? do, which is probably where the problem is. Could someone explain how the regex work with the base url? When I enter the url `http://localhost:8000/question6/test-question/no_rep:1`, `request.session['no_rep']` should be set to true, but it's not. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried `http://localhost:8000/question6/test-question?no_rep=1`?

Comment: When I enter that it automatically became `http://localhost:8000/question6/test-question/?no_rep=1` with the `/`, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your url looks like this after all substitutions (%): `r'^question(?P<id>\d+)/(/no-rep:(?P<no_rep>\w+))?'`, so:
1. Missing part for `test-question`
2. You have odd grouping around named group `no_rep` (which is legal, but [not recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-unnamed-regular-expression-groups))

So for url like `http://localhost:8000/question6/test-question/no_rep:1` your url pattern should look like this:
`r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/test-question/(?:no_rep:(?P<no_rep>\d+))?' % QUESTION_PAGE_BASE_URL.strip('/')` (you can change \d+ in the last group for \w+ if you want letters to match too).

About non-capturing groups `(?:...)` and meaning of + and ? you can read in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) of Python re module.